# The Dicke and Hopfield model of light-matter interaction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, photons, interferometry

Considering the Hamiltonian below for the normal Dicke model below;
$$\hat H = {\omega _p}{\hat a^ + }\hat a + {\omega _m}{\hat b^ + }\hat b + g\left( {{{\hat a}^ + } + \hat a} \right)\left( {{{\hat b}^ + } + \hat b} \right)(1)   $$

We can rewrite equation (1) as

$$H = {{\hat H}_p} + {{\hat H}_m} + {{\hat H}_I}   (2)
$$
Where ${{\hat H}_p}$ is the Hamiltonian of the photon subsystem,${\omega _p}$ with being the photon eigen frequency,${{\hat a}^ + }$ and ${\hat a}$ are creation (annihilation) operators of the photon cavity, ${{\hat H}_m}$
is the Hamiltonian of the magnon subsystem, with ${\omega _m}$ being the magnon eigen frequency, ${{\hat b}^ + }$ and ${\hat b}$ are magnon creation(annihilation) operators, ${{\hat H}_I}$  is the interaction term between the photon and the magnon with  being the coupling constant.
For the Hopfield model, an another term known as the diamagnetic term or ${{\hat A}^2}$ term proportional to $D{\left( {{{\hat a}^ + } + \hat a} \right)^2}$ is added thus modifying the Dicke model, where $\hat A \propto \left( {{{\hat a}^ + } + \hat a} \right)$ is  the vector potential $D$ is the diamagnetic coupling factor. We rewrite equation (1) as;

$$\hat H = {\omega _p}{\hat a^ + }\hat a + {\omega _m}{\hat b^ + }\hat b + g\left( {{{\hat a}^ + } + \hat a} \right)\left( {{{\hat b}^ + } + \hat b} \right) + D{\left( {{{\hat a}^ + } + \hat a} \right)^2}  (3)$$

Considering all the above mentioned, I have the following questions;

1. How was the Hamiltonian of equation (1) constructed and on what basis?
2. Why is the   term referred to as diamagnetic term? Why not paramagnetic or ferromagnetic?
3. What role does the Diamagnetic play in the Hopfield model of light-matter interactions?
4. What method can be used to diagonalize the Hamiltonian in equation (3)?